# Ansible - How maintain a dynamic list of data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible, jinja2

I'm building a system to deploy an entire environment in AWS. However, in the case of failure, I want to tear down everything that's already been built. Since I was planning to deploy multiple, different environments, I figured it would be better to just keep a running list of what I've made in AWS up to that point.

So I want a way to store just a simple array of the names of each component, appending the names as each part is spun up in turn,  so that at the error stage, I can just terminate everything, but this is proving to be quite head-scratching for me.

As it stands, my code looks something like this:

**top-level-playbook**

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  roles:
    - { role: make_ec2, when: "ansible_failed_task is undefined" }
         --Fails Here--
    - { role: make_ec2, when: "ansible_failed_task is undefined" }
    - { role: make_ec2, when: "ansible_failed_task is undefined" }
  post_tasks:
    - name: "do a teardown"
      *iterate through list and tear down environment*
      when: ansible_failed_task is defined
```

**make_ec2** (This is in a block/rescue)

```
---
- name: "spin up EC2
     --all the variables you need to spin up the EC2"
  register: EC2

- name: "Append List"
- set_fact:
     ec2_list: "{{ ec2_list | default | -Append ec2.string.value- }}"
```

In addition, if there are any better ways to do the tear down, please let me know as well!

Comment: without knowing more about how your roles are configured, can't you place in any of the modules that you are using for provisioning the following actions..   until: "something happens good",  retries: 20, delay: 10?? If you are already doing this, than ignore my comment :)

Comment: For the systems that require this, I already have something like that in place :)

The problem is mostly just trying to store some sort of variable to hold data once I get it back..

Answer (score 0):

> So I want a way to store just a simple array of the names of each
>   component, appending the names as each part is spun up in turn....

You can create a temp file in `pre_task` and write data into it, so if something failed, you know what to delete.   Alternatively you can replace file with DB, but the mechanics would still be the same.

> if there are any better ways to do the tear down, please let me know
>   as well!

I personally wouldn't reinvent the wheel and would just use `CloudFormation` which is a template for your AWS resources.  You can use libraries like `troposphere` to help you manage JSON structure.  So in other words if something failed, cloudformation will revert it back, and cleanup all the resources.

Comment: For various reasons, using CloudFormation really isn't an option here.

I considered using a file as well, but I figured since I would only have ~30 components tops, saving a local array of 30 items is better than doing all the associated file I/O. Is file the standard practice?